# Pygame Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available

Tags: python, pip, pygame

Hi I am trying to install pygame using `py -m pip install -U pygame --user` however I keep getting the following error:

> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pygame/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pygame/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame
> (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for pygame

I have Python 3.8 installed and pip 20.1.1 also my OS is Windows 10, is there any way that I get this installed? I am relatively new to Python.
Thanks,

Comment: A missing `ssl` module will lead to all kind of troubles and should be fixed. How did you install Python?

Comment: I directly downloaded from the website, however, I do have visual studio and jupyter installed on my PC

Comment: I feel that I am going to have so much trouble in the future with locating python, is there a way that I can get it sorted? or installed properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command.

```
py -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org pygame -vvv
```

Comment: It did not work I got this error: 
"curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate."

Comment: It did not, I does not do anything when I run 'python get-pip.py'

Comment: What do you mean when you say it does not do anything do you get an error?

Comment: did you download it using curl or manually from the website?

Comment: I used the curl command and that worked, however, when I run 'python get-pip.py' it literally does not do anything not error or nothing, it only jumps to next line

Comment: Is this in powershell or cmd?

Comment: cmd but I tried in the powershell and the same happens

Comment: ok so use the following command. python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: I just did it and I got the following:          **Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\mauro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (20.1.1)**

Comment: Do you have a proxy on you system?

Comment: try pip install --upgrade pip --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org

Comment: Same error **Could not fetch URL pypi.org/simple/pip: There was a problem ....**